# Why is the server not starting up for my ' mongoDB'?

Tags: mongodb, command-line-interface

I am trying to use 'MongoDB' as my Nosql database.I have followed many videos and tutorials on the installation of 'MongoDB' , and accordingly , 
I have set the path to my bin folder in the environment variables.

When I check the version using 'mongo --version' , I am getting the version of the 'MongoDB' as expected.The following is the screenshot of the same.

[image: Output of the 'mongo --version' command]

However , when I give the command as 'mongod' I am getting the following error.

[image: output of the 'mongod command']

Strangely though , when i try to start the client using 'mongo' command , it is starting up and trying to connect with the server at 27017. The following is a screenshot depicting the same.
[image: output for the 'mongo' command.]

why is the 'mongod' command not working for me?

Comment: Probably version mismatch? On the first screenshot, you are trying to start `mongod` from version 3.4 directory, however `mongo` shows version `4.0.0`.

Comment: verify your mongo directory path !

Comment: @TomášLinhart...how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: try to create a folder on your C drive, like this `C:\data\db` and then run `mongod command`. Once I solved this issue like this